# execute selected option by id

Tags: javascript, html, select

I want to execute the id of an option after it is selected and executed using the execute button. So for example, i choose Audi, then i want to execute id 4 after i have pressed execute.

```
<select>
 <option value="volvo" id="1">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab" id="2">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes" id="3">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi" id="4">Audi</option>
</select>
<a id="//option-chosen-id">Execute</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "execute"? Call another function?

Comment: When execute is clicked, the output of the chosen id must appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make execute of type button and use onclick to execute your Javascript code

```
<select id="abc">
 <option value="volvo" id="1">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab" id="2">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes" id="3">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi" id="4">Audi</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Execute" onclick="func()" />
<script>
      function func() {
        var b = document.getElementById("abc");
       var a= b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this it may help.
you can use onchange() in the select tag.

```
 <select onchange="call_function()" name="select">
 <option value="volvo" id="1">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab" id="2">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes" id="3">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi" id="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

in javascript you write the code for call_function().like

```
function call_function(){
// your script here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming jQuery is installed:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="volvo"    id="1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab"     id="2">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes" id="3">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi"     id="4">Audi</option>
</select>
<a id="exe">Execute</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mySelect").on("change", function() {
            $('#exe').prop('href', "//" + $('#mySelect').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will update the anchor tag's link location to be //**selected-option** once the select box is changed.

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
<script>
function abc(){
    var b = document.getElementById("abc");
    var a= b.options[b.selectedIndex].id;
    alert(a);
}   
</script>
<select id="abc">
 <option value="volvo" id="1">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab" id="2">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes" id="3">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi" id="4">Audi</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Press" onclick="abc()">
```